# Checkout payment failed email to customer

Tags: checkout, customer, email, email-templates, transactional

I want to send email to customer on checkout payment fail. That he can use alternative payment methods and etc. I can edit payment transaction failed template for this purpose and I know can change things about this at  `Configuration>Checkout` but where I can find the option for customer email?
This question is also asked on [Magento-forum](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/454543/) but no proper answer is provided by any one.

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this. It's perfectly working in my way.

> app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Helper/Data.php

Create an array like this in line 198 just before this line:

```
foreach ($result_sendTo as $recipient) {
   $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area'=>'frontend', 'store'=>$checkout->getStoreId()))
```

array

```
 $custdetail[]=array("email"=>$checkout->getCustomerEmail(),'name'  => $checkout->getCustomerFirstname());
```

then merge with $sendTo array like this:

```
$result_sendTo = array_merge((array)$sendTo, (array)$custdetail);
```

then change the variable $sendTo in foreach loop to  $result_sendTo like this:

```
foreach ($result_sendTo as $recipient) {
```

It's working.

Comment: A core modification? Are you serious?

Comment: Its a core modification but it worked for me. To me I can afford core modification currently. Thanks @user3096

Comment: One more quick question, How can I include unregistered users in Abandoned Cart list? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should move the core file in local directory and make your changes. like this : app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Helper/Data.php